# Multiplicate sum from input values with repeater_fields

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, function, advanced-custom-fields

I have written a function that sums up everything that the user fill out in the input field. But I want to multiplicate the total sum with values from my repeater field.
This is the code i have right now.

```
$(document).ready(calculate);   
$(document).on("keyup", calculate);

function calculate() {
var sum = 0;
var value1 = $("#element").val();
var value2 = $("#otherElemenet").val();
$(".o-money__answer").each(function(){
    sum += +$(this).val();

});
$("#o-exercise__totalsum").html(sum);
}
```

And this is my phpcode to get the value from repeaterfields and options field values.

```
<div id="o-exercise__totalsum">0</div>
<p><?php the_field('monetary_factor', 'option'); ?></p>
<?php if(have_rows('pengar')):while(have_rows('pengar')) : the_row();
$a_price = get_sub_field('a_price');
?>
<span><?php echo $a_price; ?></span>
<?php break; endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Comment: sum += +$(this).val(); replace this with sum += parseInt($(this).val());

Comment: Also what error are you getting?

Comment: @SmithRaval Im not getting an error i just want to know what to write for code to muliplicate the sum with the subfield values

Comment: can you please show the html of .o-money__answer ?

Comment: @SmitRaval Antal <?php echo $row['typ_av_enhet']; ?>
       
       <input type="text" value="" class="o-money__answer"><br />

      <?php endforeach; ?>

Comment: Check my answer it will give you an idea how you can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take one hidden field and make the initial value 0.

```
<input type="hidden" value="0" class="last_sum" />
```

Now on page load you have to do nothing.
On blur event of .o-money__answer you have to execute the function.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".o-money__answer").blur(function(){
        var last_sum = parseInt($(".last_sum").val());
          $(".o-money__answer").each(function(){
           last_sum += parseInt($(this).val());
          });
        $(".last_sum").val(last_sum);
        $("#o-exercise__totalsum").html(last_sum);
    });
    });
```